# В заданной строке найти месторасположение первого символа «*»

Tags: c++

```
char str[80] = "fae*fe fief oq eof jiqe[ qe. ";

char *p = str;

int Index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i){
    if (str[i] == '*')
        Index = i;
}

cout << Index << endl;
```

Через for у меня получается, а как сделать через while?

Comment: И ещё один вопрос, почему я могу задавать только один вопрос в 6 дней?

Comment: `while(*p) { if (*p == '*') { index = p-str; break;} ++p; }`

Comment: @IlyaTikhonov, приведённый в вопросе код выведет номер позиции **последнего** символа `*`, а не *первого*.

Comment: Break нужно дописать?

Comment: да. `if (str[i] == '*'){ Index = i; break;}`

Comment: `strlen(str)` в условии цикла? Ух.

Comment: А так короче: `while (*p) if (*p++ == '*') { index = --p - str; break;}` и скобочек меньше.

Comment: А на самом деле, я бы написал в одну строчку `int index = (p = strchr(str, '*')) ? p - str : -1;`

Comment: Я полностью согласен с `strchr`.  И еще я не понимаю, при чем тут таг `c++`.  Тут чистое `c`.